# Why can I see some deleted questions but trying to access others result in Not Found page?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Example 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660233/problem-asked-in-unstop-codeathon-challenge
(Blurred by me on purpose)

[image: deleted question screenshot]

Example 2: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/74732107
List of questions:

[image: question on the list]

After clicking the link:

[image: not found page screenshot]

Edit:

The other one points to `staging-ground`, so why is it listed in the list with questions?

[image: source of the page]

Comment: That second link is to a staging ground question, I expect that to be related

Comment: *"why is it listed in the list with questions"* ... most likely the same bug causing unwanted questions being shown when clicking on the "x questions with new activity" button. Those staging-ground questions aren't shown when you refresh the whole page. (I mean this bug: [Can we apply tag filters to "questions with new activity" in the Questions tab?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315217), there are several other  reports about issues related to that button)

Answer (score 9):

I can confirm that this is a bug on the Staging Ground. I noticed the behaviour on this account just before the test went live, and put it down to timing. I opened the site on a sock puppet account to make sure, however, and confirmed the problem occurring again on that as well, which doesn't have access to the beta. I mentioned it in chat over there and it has been confirmed as a bug:

> Interesting, users that don't have access to the SG can get qusetions that are going to the SG in their qusetion list; i'll post on the teams site

> @Larnu we are aware of it - fine to post it there as no one has done yet. We missed blocking it on the real-time-update on filters and tag pages

It's also [logged](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/q/31/39) as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on the Staging Ground Testing Teams site.

---

This is now, reportedly, fixed (though we have seen it occur since, and a new [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) has been logged, it might have been due to caching):

Yaakov Ellis:

> This has been fixed
>
> > on filter listing
> > cool! there's a realtime update! no more S.G. link